# Grab record satisfying multiple case statements

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to grab a record that meets multiple conditions. See below.

**DATA:**

| PERSON_ID | DOCTOR | DATE_OF_SERVICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Dr. Smith | 2022-01-01 |
| 1234 |  | 2022-01-01 |
| 1234 | Dr. Jane | 2022-03-01 |
| 1234 |  | 2022-06-01 |

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

| ID | DOCTOR | DATE_OF_SERVICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Dr. Smith | 2022-01-01 |
| 1234 | Dr. Jane | 2022-03-01 |
| 1234 |  | 2022-06-01 |

Basically, if a person_id has the same date_of_service but one record has a doctor populated and the other doesn't, take the record where the doctor is not null.

BUT - if there is only one record where there is no doctor listed, then it is okay to keep.

Is this doable? Any help would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.doctor IS NOT NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM tablename t2
            WHERE t2.person_id = t1.person_id 
              AND t2.date_of_service = t1.date_of_service 
              AND t2.doctor IS NOT NULL
          );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CaqUQPrO).

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use for the `qualify` clause in Snowflake:

```
create or replace table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::string as "PERSON_ID",
COLUMN2::string as "DOCTOR",
COLUMN3::string as "DATE_OF_SERVICE"
from (values
('1234','Dr. Smith','2022-01-01'),
('1234',null,'2022-01-01'),
('1234','Dr. Jane','2022-03-01'),
('1234',null,'2022-06-01')
);

select * from T1 
qualify (count(*)) over (partition by person_id, date_of_service) = 1 
     or doctor is not null;
```

| PERSON_ID | DOCTOR | DATE_OF_SERVICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Dr. Smith | 2022-01-01 |
| 1234 | Dr. Jane | 2022-03-01 |
| 1234 | null | 2022-06-01 |

The qualify clause works like a where clause for window functions. The `count(*) over...` part "qualifies" rows where there's only one row for a specific person_id and date_of_service. The `doctor is not null` part is self-evident and allows those rows to qualify.